# Can SQL determine which values from a set of possible column values do not exist?

Tags: sql

I have a unique column.  I also have a known set of elements that are possible values for the column.  I need to know which of the possible values are not already in the table, and as such, are suitable for insertion.

Is this possible with SQL or is post processing required?

Currently, I am using the "in" operator to select all rows where the column value equals an element in my set.  Then I remove all matched elements from my set via post processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the allowed values in a temporary table `allowed`, then use a subquery using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM allowed
WHERE allowed.val NOT IN (
    SELECT maintable.val
)
```

Some DBs will allow you to build up a table "in-place", instead of having to create a separate table.  E.g. in PostgreSQL (any version):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'foo'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'bar'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'baz'    -- etc.
) inplace_allowed
WHERE inplace_allowed.val NOT IN (
    SELECT maintable.val
)
```

More modern versions of PostgreSQL (and perhaps other DBs) will let you use the slightly nicer [VALUES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-values.html) syntax to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

To do this entirely in SQL you will need to create a separate table with one column.  Each row holds one value from the known set of elements.  Assuming the table is called ElementList and the other table is called Existing:

```
 SELECT * FROM ElementList WHERE Element NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Element FROM Existing)
```

Depending on what database engine you're using you may be able to use a temporary table to create and hold the list without saving it permanently in the database.  However, storing the list of allowed elements is valuable for constraining the Element column in the Existing table (and for presenting the user with allowed Elements in the user interface).